# sp_whoisactive time columns

Tags: sql-server, sp-whoisactive

I am looking at data captured with the help of sp_whoisactive.

```
session_id: 1016
blocked_session_count: 24
Login_time : 29/03/2018  12:14:59
tran_start_time : 29/03/2018  12:14:59
start_time: 29/03/2018  12:15:59
status: sleeping
open_tran_count :1
```

The login_time and tran_start_time are the same for this session_id.
But start_time is after a minute.

Does this mean the session entered sleeping state @ 29/03/2018  12:15:59 ??

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you looked through the [documentation](http://whoisactive.com/docs/)? There are a few pages that I think explain what the columns mean here.

Comment: I did go through the documentation. This is all is said about it.

Each set of columns deserves some description, and we’ll start with Time and Status. These columns tell you how long your query has been running ([start_time] and its cousin, the “convenience column” [dd hh:mm:ss.mss]), how much longer things might be running ([percent_complete]), whether anything is running at all ([status]), and a record of when you asked ([collection_time]).

Comment: Found the answer i was looking for in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tran_start_time] - Date and time that the first transaction opened by a session caused a transaction log write to occur.

[start_time] -  For active requests, shows the time the request started |   For sleeping sessions, shows the time the last batch completed

[login_time] -  Shows the time that the session connected

Comment: I think it's important to note the difference between the start of a batch and the start of the execution of the active statement. I feel like "request" could be construed as either, and the current statement might have started executing a minute later than the current batch because of, say, a `WAITFOR DELAY` *or* because previous statements in the batch really took a minute to run. Since it is *exactly* a minute, my money's on the former.